# nodejs response.end duplicate event

Tags: node.js

I am using the nodejs http library. I see two logs on the console. Why? And i take the field `response.end(JSON.stringify({'asd': 'asd'}));` result: one log.

```
var config = require('./config.js');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var requester = require('request');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', config.allowOrgin);
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,X-AUTH-TOKEN,accept,customheader,x-my-custom-header,request_id');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    response.writeHead(200, "OK", { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    var urlData = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var requestUrl = config.appUrl + urlData.pathname;
    var formData = querystring.parse(body);

    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data.toString();
    });
    console.log('asd');
    response.end(JSON.stringify(body));
}).listen(config.port, config.host);
console.log(config.host + ':' + config.port);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're hitting the server from your web browser, you'll see two console logs because the browser also sends a request to `/favicon.ico` to check if your website provides an icon to display in the browser tab.

Replace your console log with `console.log('req.url: ' + req.url);` to see.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon